# Ionic Geolocation Current Location

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, geolocation

I have a problem with combining `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` with `Geolocation.watchPosition()`. My application was working perfectly before I added the watchPosition. I need to use it to display the user's location on the map as a marker and whenever the user moves, the marker should move on the map.

My application's logic is, creating the map with dummy lat and lng then learning the current lat and lng and zooms at this location add marker and when the user moves the marker should move.

The error occurs when I change the tab and come back. So the map displayed the first time when the application started, but whenever I want to change tab and come back it displays a timeout error. Here is my code:

```
  async ngAfterViewInit() {
    await this.createMap();
    await this.getCurrentLocation();
    this.startWatchingPosition();

    //this.addPolygonsToMap();
    //this.addStations();
    //await this.show_scooters();
    console.log("la lo", this.lat, this.lng);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroyMap();
    this.mapReady = false;
    if (this.watch != null) Geolocation.clearWatch(this.watch);
  }

 async getCurrentLocation() {
    try {

      const location = await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
      console.log("deneme2")
      this.lat = location.coords.latitude;
      this.lng = location.coords.longitude;
      this.la = location.coords.latitude.toString();
      this.lo = location.coords.longitude.toString();
      console.log(
        "old lat and lng",
        location.coords.latitude,
        location.coords.longitude
      );
      this.map.setCamera({
        coordinate: {
          lat: this.lat,
          lng: this.lng,
        },
        zoom: 17,
      });
      this.useerLocation(this.lat, this.lng);
      this.addPolygonsToMap();
      this.addStations();
      this.show_scooters();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error getting current location:", error);
    }
  }

  async startWatchingPosition() {
    console.log("girdi");
    this.watch = await Geolocation.watchPosition(
      {
        timeout: 10000,
        maximumAge: 0,
      },
      async (position, err) => {
        if (position) {
          console.log("np ", position);
          this.map.setCamera({
            coordinate: {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude,
            },
            zoom: 17,
          });
          if (this.locationID != null) {
            this.map.removeMarker(this.locationID);
          }

          this.useerLocation(
            position.coords.latitude,
            position.coords.longitude
          );
        } else {
          console.log("error is", err);
        }
      }
    );
```

}

When I added the startwatching to the comments it works but when ı use it with the getcurrentlocation it displays timeout error

Comment: You can try to separate the Initialization Logic: Instead of using ```Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()``` inside ```ngAfterViewInit()```, you can call it earlier in your component's lifecycle, such as in the constructor or ```ngOnInit()```. That way, you can get that the initial position earlier and set before starting to watch for changes.

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: the logic seems off. getCurrentLocation is called in the wrong place. instead of inside of the life cycle hook, it should be placed inside of the createMap method AFTER creating the map logic. and then after getCurrentLocation, you run the startWatchingPosition method AFTER the current location was given.

Comment: The reason why getCurrentLocation is not inside createMap() is simply due to the delay in obtaining the location. If I use the code inside createMap(), I would have to wait for the current location to be fetched before the map displays. However, by having this map initially created with default latitude and longitude values, the map centers on these coordinates. Later, when the current location is determined, the map then re-centers with the new coordinates.